# Java - LWJGL - OpenAL - Understanding some code

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

Hell coders , I am currently studying OpenAL with LWJGL and I can not understand what these lines of code do(the comments represent what I think they are doing , may you please tell me the right things? I have read the Javadocs and did not understood a thing . I googled and googled.)

```
WaveData data = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("res/sound.wav")));//generate data from the file (binary data?)
    int buffer = alGenBuffers();//generate an empty buffer
    alBufferData(buffer,data.format,data.data,data.samplerate);//assign previously generated data to buffer
    data.dispose();//what does this line do? (I can not understand what dispose means. Throw away or give the data?)    
    int source = alGenSources();//generate source(What does source mean here?)
    alSourcei(source , AL_BUFFER, buffer);//set a property the the source. arg # 1 is the property type , arg # 0 is the source to set the property at and arg # 3 is the value to pass as a property.
```

Please help me become a better programmer .
 Regards ~ Teo

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here : https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/WaveData.java    data.dispose() clears the ByteBuffer which doesn't discard data but reset read/write position (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#clear%28%29)

Comment: What about the other ones? So , dispose() before read/write to buffer. Aw by the way , I tested it without the data.dispose(); line and it worked perfectly

Comment: Yes, it works well in this use case. But imagine you somewhere else in your application you want to stream the buffer again. You would like to start from the begin, but the internal position in the buffer is pointing somewhere else. Therefore the call to data.dispose.

Comment: dispose after doing alBufferData() or before using it again?